# How to combine element transformations?

Tags: javascript, css, html, linear-algebra, css-transforms

In HTML5 I want to implement transform functionality to canvas element, so user can `translate` (move), `scale` (zoom in/out) and `rotate` the canvas element. Each such tranformation can be done with different transform-origin point.

First tranformation is easy:

```
function transform(el, value, origin) {
  el.style.Transform = value;
  el.style.MozTransform = value;
  el.style.msTransform = value;
  el.style.OTransform = value;
  el.style.webkitTransform = value;
  el.style.TransformOrigin = origin;
  el.style.MozTransformOrigin = origin;
  el.style.msTransformOrigin = origin;
  el.style.OTransformOrigin = origin;
  el.style.webkitTransformOrigin = origin;
}

transform(myCanvas, 'translate('+ dx +'px, ' + dy + 'px) ' +
                    'scale(' + zoom + ', ' + zoom + ') ' +
                    'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
                    cx + 'px ' + cy + 'px');
```

User will move or zoom or rotate the element, not everything at once, so some parameters of tranformation will stay default *(dx = 0, dy = 0, zoom = 1, angle = 0)*.

After such tranformation, if user wants to make another transformation (and antother, and another...), how can I combine *(dx1, dy1, zoom1, angle1, cx1, cy1)* with *(dx2, dy2, zoom2, angle2, cx2, cy2)* to get final values that can be combine later with new tranformation parameters? I cannot append another tranformation to `transform` parameter, because `tranform-origin` may be different. Is there a formula how to combine tranformations with different transform-origin points?

Comment: Have you tried to visualize it? Draw a box on a paper. Then, consider what happens when you want to translate/rotate/scale the box. And again.

Comment: @RobW - I tried a lot for over a week :-/ I am able to combine unlimited move (translate) and zoom (scale) tranformations, but once I have rotation involved, I am lost...

Comment: I'm not sure the linear-algebra tag belongs on this question. It's more about combining CSS properties than using linear algebra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to learn matrix math. According to [the CSS Transform specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformation-matrix-computation)

> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X, Y and Z values of ‘transform-origin’.
> 3. Multiply by each of the transform functions in ‘transform’ property in turn
> 4. Translate by the negated computed X, Y and Z values of ‘transform-origin’

In other words, `transform-origin: A; transform: B` is the same as `transform: translate(-A) B translate(A)`. (Transformations apply from right to left, so the first thing you want to happen goes at the end.)

So use the above rules to eliminate `transform-origin` and now you just have plain transforms you can concatenate.

Example:

1. `transform-origin: 5px 5px; transform: translate(10px, 40px)`
2. `transform-origin: 25px 30px; transform: scale(2)`
3. `transform-origin: 10px 10px; transform: rotate(30deg)`

becomes

1. `transform: translate(-5px, -5px) translate(10px, 40px) translate(5px, 5px)`
2. `transform: translate(-25px, -30px) scale(2) translate(25px, 30px)`
3. `transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg) translate(10px, 10px)`

Now you can combine them since they all agree on the origin (i.e., no origin)

`transform: translate(-5px, -5px) translate(10px, 40px) translate(5px, 5px) translate(-25px, -30px) scale(2) translate(25px, 30px) translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(30deg) translate(10px, 10px)`

Of course you can collapse the consecutive translations if you want

`transform: translate(-15px, 10px) scale(2) translate(15px, 20px) rotate(30deg) translate(10px, 10px)`

Or you can dig out your math textbook and [compute the final transformation matrix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nu0WpF-1_LM).

**Edit**: Transforms apply right to left.

Comment: Either one of us didn't catch what Omega wanted. I think the problem is that 3 transformations are known, but their origins *are changed* by the previous transformation(s). Plus, I never worked with CSS `transform` so far, but shouldn't you *subtract* the origin *first* and add it later?

Comment: @MaxArt I thought so too about the negative coming first but the spec says otherwise. Maybe it is a spec bug. Try it both ways and see which comes out better.

Comment: Nice one, it didn't occur to me that multiple functions with the same name can be used in one line.

Comment: @RobW All the function names are [just shorthand for the matrix(...) function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#mathematical-description). Besides, there's an example of this [in the CSS Transforms spec itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-function-lists).

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to deal with matrix transformations.

Every linear operation can be represented with a 3x3 matrix and a 3x1 vector that you can apply on the point of the plane. If *p* is a point, *M* the matrix and *q* the other vectory, every linear transformation can be represented as *Mp + q*.

If you have a 2d point, then its vector will be [*x; y; 1*] (a vertical vector), while the matrix can be of several form.

For translations, the matrix is just the identity matrix. The vector *q* is the translation vector.

For scaling, *M* is like

```
    [a 0 0]
M = [0 b 0]
    [0 0 1]
```

where *a* and *b* are scaling factor for *x* and *y* respectively. The vector *q* is null.

For rotations, say of an angle *a*, you'll get

```
    [cos(a) -sin(a) 0]
M = [sin(a)  cos(a) 0]
    [  0       0    1]
```

and *q* is null again.

There are matrices for skewing, too. So, if you have to apply three consecutive transformations, you'll have to apply these kind of linear transformations. Your problem is that you have to deal with origins, too, so you'll have to subtract the vector *o* from *p*, than apply *M*, add *q* and then *o* again.

Let's say you have these transformation (*M1, q1, o1*) and (*M2, q2, o2*). When you apply the first one you get

```
p1 = M1 * (p - o1) + q1 + o1
```

Then you have to apply the second transformation:

```
p2 = M2 * (p1 - o2) + q2 + o2
```

In the end you'll get:

```
p2 = M2 * (M1 * (p - o1) + q1 + o1 - o2) + q2 + o2
```

And so on with and eventual third (*M3, q3, o3*).

A mess? It looks like. But things can be simplyfied a bit if you know how the matrices look like.

Now, do the math, and apply it to `transform: matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)`.

Comment: In the last formula I wrote exactly how to deal with origins. Remember, although matrix product isn't commutative, it's linear anyway, so `p2 = M2*M1*(p - o1) + M2*(q1+o1-o2) + q2+o2`.

Comment: Just to make it clear, your combined transformation has *M2xM1* as the matrix, *o1* as the origin, and *M2(q1+o1-o2) + q2+o2* as the translation vector.

Comment: You are genius, but I am not. Sorry. I have just matrixes (M1, M2, ...) for transformations and origins (o1, o2, ...). I don't want to calculate each point (p), I want to calculate final matrix (M) that can be used as combination of multiple transformations. Am I missing something?

Comment: No sir, you're correct. But you have to calculate the matrix and the translation vector, then use their values in `transform: matrix(...)`. My suggestion is to create a function to combine two linear transformations, knowing their kind (scaling, rotating, translating) and parameters.